# How to make the hero from my game to be the same in all levels?

Tags: logic-bricks

When I made the other levels I have to change the names from the logics because I copied my hero, bad guys and amunnition from level 1. I have to change a lot of things then. How can I do to make all the important elements and characters to be with the same name in all the scenes? or a solution to my problem..

Comment: make him in a separate file and link him, that way he carries over hte exact same every time you link him. any changes will be updated to all instances.